# how to create a directory in my application asp.net core 3.1 and used

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

when I create a directory in my application the folder name is displayed in the project via Windows Explorer but not in my studion visual explorer
[in windows explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZLZ3.png)

[in visuel studion explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBY7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you created `folder` in windows explorer directly. So you can't see it in your visual studio.

You can click the `Show All files` and you will see the `folder` you created. Then you need right click, and click the `Include In Project`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: no I created it through code c#, and I would also like to know if every time I create a file through code c# it would have to go through what you just mentioned above